# If f, g : X $\rightarrow$ [0,1] are continuous and surjective where X is a connected topological space, there exists x$\in$X such that f(x)=g(x).

Tags: general-topology

Let f and g be continuous, surjective functions from X to [0,1] where X is a connected topological space, prove that there exists x$\in$X such that f(x)=g(x). Not sure where to start.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $f-g$, is it positive or negative?

Comment: There are $a, b \in X$ such that $f(a)=0, g(b)=1$...Now consider the continuous map $f-g$....

Comment: You should consider the new function $f-g$ that is defined as $f(x)-g(x)$ which maps $X$ to the real numbers. Now you can use that $f$ and $g$ are continuous to conclude some properties of $f-g$ which will in the end give you the exsitence of an $x$ where $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: $f(a)-g(a)=-g(a)\leq 0$ and $f(b)-g(b)\ge 0$ so by connctiness there is x such that....